# An arithmetic inequality

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $r=p_1^{a_1}\cdot p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_\ell^{a_\ell}$ be a positive integer, where $p_1,\ldots,p_\ell$ are distinct primes and $a_1,\ldots,a_\ell$ are at least $2$. I have a huge computational evidence that
$$\prod_{i=1}^\ell p_i^{\frac{a_i^2}{4}}\le r^{\frac{\log_2 r}{4}+1-\ell},$$
except when $r\in \{36,72,900\}$. However, I have no clue in how to prove that. Morally, in my opinion, it does make sense. When $\ell=1$, the worse case is when $p_1=2$ and in that case one has equality here. However, as $\ell$ increases, $r^{\log_2r/4}$ is a large upper estimate of the left and side and hence it is conceivable that one can shave off a $r^{1-\ell}$.

Indeed, if $a_1$ is the largest of the $a_i$s, then
$$\prod_{i=1}^\ell p_i^{\frac{a_i^2}{4}}\le \left(\prod_{\ell=1}^\ell p_i^{a_i}\right)^{\frac{a_1}{4}}=r^{\frac{a_1}{4}}\le r^{\frac{\log_2r}{4}},$$
regardless of the assumption $a_i\ge 2$. Therefore, the real question is whether one can shave off $r^{1-\ell}$ when $a_1,\ldots,a_\ell\ge 2$.